# Recursive sequence is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have to show, that the sequence $g(n+1) = \frac{2ag(n)}{a+g(n)^2}$
is increasing for $a>0$ and $g(0)>0$. I know that it holds for $g(n)^2<a$
since $2a/(a+g(n)^2)>1$. But for $g(n)^2>a$ the opposite seems to be true.

I assume my professor forgot some initial restrictions but maybe I am overseeing something. I’d appreciate your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Maybe this kind of visualization will help: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lmg2s8iccl

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to see that such a recurrence cannot be strictly increasing for all such initial choices.  For instance, $a = 1$ and $g(0) = 2$ yields $g(1) = \frac{4}{5}$.  In fact, we can see that $\sqrt{a}$ is a fixed point of the sequence by solving $$g = \frac{2ag}{a+g^2}$$ for $g$.  If $g(0) > \sqrt{a}$, then we have $$\frac{g(1)}{g(0)} = \frac{2a}{a+g(0)^2} < \frac{2a}{a+a} = 1,$$ hence $g(1) < g(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{2ax}{a+x^2}$ be the function that defines the recursive sequence $\bigl(g(n)\bigr)_{n\ge 0}$.

This sequence is increasing if all $g(n)$ live in $A\subset\mathbf R$ such that, for all $x\in A$, $f (x)\ge x\:$ and $\:f(A)\subset A$.

Now $\quad f(x)\ge x \iff 2ax \ge x(a+x^2)\iff ax\ge x^3\iff\begin{cases}x^2\le a&\text{if }x\ge 0,\\x^2\ge a&\text{if }x<0.\end{cases}$

It is clear  from the hypotheses that we're in the first case ($g(n)>0$). So there remains to prove by induction that all $g(n)$ live in the interval $I=\bigl[0,\sqrt a\bigr]$, i.e. $f(I)\subset I$.

Answer (score 0):

By simplification,

$$g(n+1)=\frac{2ag(n)}{a+g^2(n)}\lessgtr g(n)$$

is equivalent to

$$a\lessgtr g^2(n).$$

But note that after a single iteration,

$$g(n)\le\sqrt a.$$

Comment: @BarryCipra: yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: @BarryCipra: you are quite right, $g$ decreases toward $\sqrt a$ *and passes it*.

Comment: I've deleted my earlier comments, since they're no longer relevant. But I think you still need to include a proof that $g(n)\le\sqrt{a}\implies g(n+1)\le\sqrt a$. That doesn't in itself fall out of the equivalence $g(n+1)\ge g(n)\iff a\ge g^2(a)$ (or if it does I don't see how).

Answer (score 0):

If you let $g_n=\sqrt a\, h_n$, you face the problem of
$$h_{n+1}=\frac {2h_n}{1+h_n^2}\implies h_n=\tanh \left(2^n\,\,k\right)\implies g_n=\sqrt a\,\tanh \left(2^n\,\,k\right)$$

So, no problem.

Comment: What is $k{}{}{}$?

Comment: @BarryCipra. An arbitrary constant to be fixed by $g(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the recursion as

$${1\over g(n+1)}={a+g(n)^2\over2ag(n)}={1\over2}\left({1\over g(n)}+{g(n)\over a} \right)$$

and now let $g(n)=1/h(n)$ and $a=1/A$, so that the recursion is

$$h(n+1)={1\over2}\left(h(n)+{A\over h(n)}\right)$$

and

$$h(n)-h(n+1)={1\over2}\left(h(n)-{A\over h(n)}\right)$$

To show that $g(1)\le g(2)\le g(3)\le\cdots$, we need to show $h(1)\ge h(2)\ge h(3)\ge\cdots$, i.e., $h(n)-h(n+1)\ge0$. But, by AGM, we have, for $n\ge0$,

$$h(n+1)={1\over2}\left(h(n)+{A\over h(n)}\right)\ge\sqrt{h(n)\cdot{A\over h(n)}}=\sqrt A$$

and therefore

$$h(n)-h(n+1)={1\over2}\left(h(n)-{A\over h(n)}\right)\ge{1\over2}\left(\sqrt A-{A\over\sqrt A}\right)=0$$

Remark: As has been noted, the increasing nature of $g(n)$ need not kick in at $n=0$. For example, if $a=1$ and $g(0)=2$, then $g(1)=4/5\lt g(0)$.